# How to draw straight lines inside google map polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have created a google map using `google map javascript API V3`. I am drawing number of zipcode polygons. The polygons are of different colors depending upon some condition. Now I want to draw straight lines/ hash marks inside some of the polygons depending upon certain criteria. How can we do it. Below is the code which I have written for drawing the polygons.

```
{% if zip.zip_info.zip_polygon %}
    var path = [
        {% for polycoord in zip.zip_info.zip_polygon %}
            new google.maps.LatLng({{polycoord.1}}, {{polycoord.0}}),
        {% endfor %}
        ];

    var polygon_{{ forloop.counter }} = new google.maps.Polygon(
    {
        path:path, 
        clickable:true,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.15,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: fillColor,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        zipcode: '{{zip.zip_info.zipcode}}'
    });

    polygon_{{ forloop.counter }}.setMap(map);

{% endif %}
```

I am also givinging the image link of my requirement.

[image]

You can see in the image some of the polygons are shaded with straight lines, and some are shaded with only colors.

Comment: Sounds like you want a fill "texture", like this [enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=598)

Comment: Yeah want to add a texture, otherwords we can say i want to draw lines inside polygon. can we do it.

Comment: You can't do it with the API at this time. You can vote for that enhancement request (or find another better one for your purpose, or create a new one).  You may be able to do something with Polylines, but it will probably impact the performance.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip. But where can I post the request for enhancement of API or where can I vote. Please guide.

Comment: The link in my first comment. (https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=598)

Answer (score 8):

I have been working on the same issue.  This is what I have so far: [**jsFiddle of Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/7YLtY/)

The `BW.PolyLineFill` function creates a [Custom Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays).  It takes 4 parameters with the last two being optional.

```
 1. path: an array of Google LatLng objects   
 2. map: the map to attach theoverlay to 
 3. fillColor: (optional) the color of the fill, default is red. 
 4. strokeColor: (optional) the stroke color, default is black
```

I haven't tested the performance and it probably still needs more tweaking, but it should get you started.

Relevant code:

```
PolyLineFill.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
function PolyLineFill(poly, map, fill, stroke) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < poly.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(poly[i]);
    }

    //initialize all properties.
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.map_ = map;
    this.div_ = null;
    this.poly_ = poly;
    this.polysvg_ = null;
    this.fill_ = fill;
    this.stroke_ = stroke;

    // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay
    this.setMap(map);
}

PolyLineFill.prototype.onAdd = function () {
    // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';

    //createthe svg element
    var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var svg = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg");
    svg.setAttributeNS(null, "preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

    var def = document.createElementNS(svgns, "defs");

    //create the pattern fill 
    var pattern = document.createElementNS(svgns, "pattern");
    pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "lineFill");
    pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
    pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "patternTransform", "rotate(-45)");
    pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "7");
    pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "7");
    def.appendChild(pattern);

    var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "rectFill");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", this.fill_ || "red");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill-opacity", "0.3");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", this.stroke_ || "#000");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", "7,7");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "7");
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "7");
    pattern.appendChild(rect);

    svg.appendChild(def);

    //add polygon to the div
    var p = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
    p.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "url(#lineFill)");
    p.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "#000");
    p.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "1");
    //set a reference to this element;
    this.polysvg_ = p;
    svg.appendChild(p);

    div.appendChild(svg);

    // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
    this.div_ = div;

    // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.
    // We'll add this overlay to the overlayLayer pane.
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
}

PolyLineFill.prototype.AdjustPoints = function () {
    //adjust the polygon points based on the projection.
    var proj = this.getProjection();
    var sw = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    var ne = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

    var points = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.poly_.length; i++) {
        var point = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.poly_[i]);
        if (i == 0) {
            points += (point.x - sw.x) + ", " + (point.y - ne.y);
        } else {
            points += " " + (point.x - sw.x) + ", " + (point.y - ne.y);
        }
    }
    return points;
}

PolyLineFill.prototype.draw = function () {
    // Size and position the overlay. We use a southwest and northeast
    // position of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
    // We need to retrieve the projection from this overlay to do this.
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

    // Retrieve the southwest and northeast coordinates of this overlay
    // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
    // We'll use these coordinates to resize the DIV.
    var sw = overlayProjection
                .fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    var ne = overlayProjection
                .fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

    // Resize the image's DIV to fit the indicated dimensions.
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';

    this.polysvg_.setAttributeNS(null, "points", this.AdjustPoints());
}

PolyLineFill.prototype.onRemove = function () {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
}
window.BW = {};
window.BW.PolyLineFill = PolyLineFill;
```

Comment: Any further progress on this?  Looks like it works, but as soon as you zoom things don't look correct.

Comment: @BigDubb could you be more specific to what is not working?  The overlay example in the fiddle example above doesn't align exactly with the boundaries defined on the Google map since I quickly grabbed some Geodata to use for the example. The map projections may be a little different between the one used to gather the data and Google's projections.  More accurate data would have better results, or at least data consistent with Google's chosen projection.  I believe Google uses a Mercator projection, so if you use another type, you will get a slight shift when translating to screen coordinates.

Comment: I fire this up in Chrome. Zoom in on Utah and once I get past a specific zoom level it stops dawing the polygon correctly. Parts of it don't render and if you zoom in enough it just disappears all together.

Comment: I have implemented your solution in my application and I'm having the same problem @BigDubb has seen. I will check the code to see if I can fix it unless you already have a patch to solve it.

Comment: I have fixed the weird behavior when you zoomed in the map (the `svg` was being trimmed). I have added a css class to give 100% to its height and width. Now the zoom issue is solved. 

On the other hand I have changed the type of the shape rendered. I have drawn a `path` instead a `polygon` because in my tests, the `path` element was responding better to mouse events as mouse over, mouse click...

[Link to my example](http://jsfiddle.net/9gvsq3od/)

Comment: If only now someone would point the way how to make it work with multipolygons (polygons with holes in it) :)

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on Bryan Weaver's solution to get it working for editable polygons using the drawing manager. here is my [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/HeitorZ/tgu6brdq/5/)

```js
function initialize() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
     zoom: 5,
     center: {
       lat: 24.886,
       lng: -70.268
     },
     mapTypeId: 'terrain'
   });

   var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
     drawingControl: true,
     drawingControlOptions: {
       position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
       drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
     },

     polygonOptions: {
       fillOpacity: 0,
       strokeWeight: 1,
       strokeColor: '#ff0000',
       clickable: true,
       editable: true,
       draggable: true,
     }
   });

   drawingManager.setMap(map);
   google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
     var poly = event.overlay;
     poly.bk = new BW.PolyLineFill(poly.getPath(), this.map, "red", "#000");

     google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'dragstart', function(event) {
       if (poly.bk != null) {
         poly.bk.setMap(null);
         poly.bk = null
       }
       poly.isBeingDragged = true;
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'dragend', function(event) {
       if (poly.bk != null) {
         poly.bk.setMap(null);
         poly.bk = null
       }
       poly.bk = new BW.PolyLineFill(poly.getPath(), poly.map, "red", "#000");
       poly.isBeingDragged = false;
     });


     google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(), 'set_at', function(event) {
       if (poly.isBeingDragged) return;
       console.log('set_at');
       if (poly.bk != null) {
         poly.bk.setMap(null);
         poly.bk = null
       }
       poly.bk = new BW.PolyLineFill(poly.getPath(), poly.map, "red", "#000");
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(event) {
       if (poly.bk != null) {
         poly.bk.setMap(null);
         poly.bk = null
       }
       poly.bk = new BW.PolyLineFill(poly.getPath().b, poly.map, "red", "#000");
     });


     drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
   });

 }

 ///Start custom poly fill code
 PolyLineFill.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

 function PolyLineFill(poly, map, fill, stroke) {
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < poly.length; i++) {
     bounds.extend(poly.getAt(i));
   }

   //initialize all properties.
   this.bounds_ = bounds;
   this.map_ = map;
   this.div_ = null;
   this.poly_ = poly;
   this.polysvg_ = null;
   this.fill_ = fill;
   this.stroke_ = stroke;

   // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay
   this.setMap(map);
 }

 PolyLineFill.prototype.onAdd = function() {
   // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
   div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
   div.style.position = 'absolute';

   //https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_reference.asp
   //createthe svg element
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
   var svg = document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg");
   svg.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "100%");
   svg.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "100%");
   svg.setAttributeNS(null, "preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

   //A container for referenced elements
   var def = document.createElementNS(svgns, "defs");

   //create the pattern fill 
   var pattern = document.createElementNS(svgns, "pattern");
   //***************************CHANGE PATTERN HERE**********************************     
   pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "lineFill");
   pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
   //pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "patternTransform", "rotate(-33)");

   pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "60");
   pattern.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "60");
   def.appendChild(pattern);

   var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "rectFill");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "green");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "fill-opacity", "0.25");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "#0000FF");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "8");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-opacity", "0.25");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", "10 10");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "5");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "5");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "50");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "50");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "rx", "25");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "ry", "25");
   pattern.appendChild(rect);

   svg.appendChild(def);

   //add polygon to the div
   var p = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
   p.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "url(#lineFill)");
   //set a reference to this element;
   this.polysvg_ = p;
   svg.appendChild(p);

   div.appendChild(svg);

   // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
   this.div_ = div;

   // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.
   // We'll add this overlay to the overlayLayer pane.
   var panes = this.getPanes();
   panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
 }

 PolyLineFill.prototype.AdjustPoints = function() {
   //adjust the polygon points based on the projection.
   var proj = this.getProjection();
   var sw = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
   var ne = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

   var points = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < this.poly_.length; i++) {
     var point = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.poly_.getAt(i));
     if (i == 0) {
       points += (point.x - sw.x) + ", " + (point.y - ne.y);
     } else {
       points += " " + (point.x - sw.x) + ", " + (point.y - ne.y);
     }
   }
   return points;
 }

 PolyLineFill.prototype.draw = function() {
   // Size and position the overlay. We use a southwest and northeast
   // position of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
   // We need to retrieve the projection from this overlay to do this.
   var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

   // Retrieve the southwest and northeast coordinates of this overlay
   // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
   // We'll use these coordinates to resize the DIV.
   var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
   var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

   // Resize the image's DIV to fit the indicated dimensions.
   var div = this.div_;
   div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
   div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
   div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
   div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';

   this.polysvg_.setAttributeNS(null, "points", this.AdjustPoints());
 }

 PolyLineFill.prototype.onRemove = function() {
   this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
   this.div_ = null;
 }
 window.BW = {};
 window.BW.PolyLineFill = PolyLineFill;
 ///end poly fill code


 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


 //**************************velho
 function showArrays(event) {
   if (this.overlay)
     this.overlay.setMap(null)
   this.overlay = new BW.PolyLineFill(this.getPath().b, this.map, "red", "#000");
 }
```

```css
     html,
     body {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }
     
     #map-canvas,
     #map_canvas {
       height: 100%;
     }
     
     @media print {
       html,
       body {
         height: auto;
       }
       #map_canvas {
         height: 650px;
       }
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing&.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done in CANVAS:

```
http://home.provide.net/~bratliff/hawaii/
```

Click the "style" radio choices to see other optional patterns.

Comment: Yeah I saw the example in the link, which is working. But can we do it  using google map V3 API js.

Comment: This only works on static images, probably why they are using google static maps.