# Google Maps - Polygon with hole and custom background

Tags: google-maps, polygon

I want to draw a polygon on Google Maps with a complex background (striped for example). This https://stackoverflow.com/a/15840086/3020903 SO pretty much got me covered on 99% of the cases. It shows how to use custom overlays for this. Problem with this is, it does not support multidimensional coordinate arrays (e.g polygons with holes) and I currently have no idea how to achieve this. I am aware that polygons themselves support custom holes in them, but I need a "striped background" polygon with a hole in it.
One idea was to cut the polygon to multiple ones so that no single one would have a hole in it, but that seems very complex, as my polygons and holes in them might be extremely complex. Even if I could get it working, it will probably break pattern repetition. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working after some fiddling with this JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9gvsq3od/

Basic idea is in combining SVG's `fill-rule="evenodd"` property with a two dimensional LatLng array and a bit modification to `PolyLineFill.prototype.AdjustPoints()` to handle the two-dimensional coordinate array.

Heres a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/o4phfL6c/

Comment: freaking awesome bro, Thanks for the solution