# Is there way to fill cross inside polygon in Google maps reactjs application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not able to show a cross or any kind of pattern inside a polygon which I want to show Google maps using reactjs. there are not as such properties of polygon available.

I tried to use svg with OverlayView component to show in polygon Google maps in reactjs. I am expecting when i see polygon it's show pattern inside polygon

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n21p5.png

Comment: Can you show us your code, and possibly make a sketch of the expected outcome?

Comment: I want to fill the polygon mesh pattern like above image link in Google map using javascript

Comment: Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46201183)? To test it out, draw a polygon on the map. Glancing at the code, it seems that example uses predefined SVGs as a texture / polygon overlay.

Comment: Yes, But on the zoom level, it's not shown in the polygon it changes accordingly. And I am using @react-google-maps/api package in which I want to  find solution to fill polygon with mesh.

Comment: So the mesh scale should always stay the same? It shouldn't scale up and down based on zoom level?

Comment: When we use OverlayView to show mesh inside Polygon. On zoom level it's change size. Some time it's show inside as well as outside polygon on one scale. some time it's take polygon small area.

So, I want any zoom scale it's stay inside polygon don't show anywhere else. only fill inside polygon.